# Finding a duplicate value in a column and with other columns while inputs have different formats

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning

I hope everyone is alright.
I have a data set that contains three columns:

`column 1` includes all the `IDs`, in this column there might me duplicated `IDs`

`column 2` includes all the `phone_numbers` related to the `IDs`. `phone_numbers` are captured in different formats and need to cleaned and written in one single format. Each `ID` might have more than one unique `phone_number`

`column 3` includes all the `random phone numbers` related to the `IDs` but form a different source.

I need to have `three output columns`:

`output_1` indicates if an `ID` has more than one `phone_number`

`output_2` indicates if an `ID` has the same `phone_number` with the `phone_number` of any other `IDs`

`output_3` indicates if an `ID` has the same `phone_number` with any `random phone number` even if it is from same `ID`

My data looks like

```
id <- c(1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5,2,3,7)
phone_number <- c("4121234567","3137894561",
             "1234567788","(412)123-45%67",
             "919-789-1$122","(123)1112233",
             "(412)1234567","1234567788",
             "123-11%12233")

phone_random<- c("na","4121234567",
            "","na",
            "123-1112233",
            "na","","919-789-1$122","")

df <- data.frame(id, phone_number,phone_random)

df %>% head() 
  id       phone_id phone_random
1  1     4121234567           na
2  2     3137894561   4121234567
3  3     1234567788             
4  1 (412)123-45%67           na
5  4  919-789-1$122  123-1112233
6  5   (123)1112233           na
```

Please let me know if further information is needed in this case.

Thank you so much for your help in advance!

Comment: Is `(412)123-45%67` considered to be "the same" as `4121234567`? That is, are we only to consider the numeric characters?

Comment: @markyoung , yes technically it is a same number with input errors

Answer (score 0):

As a beginning you can clean your `phone_number` and `phone_random` as

```
df$phone_number <- gsub('\\D', '', df$phone_number)

df$phone_random <- gsub('\\D', '', df$phone_random)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am looking into a solution in ``` dplyr``` to write all the code chunk. Appreciate your help!

Comment: @akrun , wondering if you have any ideas?